# Update Table Set Column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm trying to run the code below and I keep getting this error back:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 
>   Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , > >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been terminated.

I'm trying to make a field to identify individual users.  Any suggestions?

```
UPDATE dbo.AAASTA_CONTACT
SET dbo.AAASTA_CONTACT.ALIAS_KEY =
(SELECT(SUBSTRING(COALESCE(CAST(ADDR.ADDR_ZIPCODE AS NCHAR(5)), '     ') 
        + COALESCE(CAST(UPPER(CON2.CON_LAST_NAME)AS NCHAR(5)), '     ') 
        + COALESCE(CAST(UPPER(CON2.CON_FST_NAME)AS NCHAR(5)), '     ') 
        + COALESCE(CAST(UPPER(ADDR.ADDR_ADDR_NAME) AS NCHAR(5)), '     '),1,20))
FROM dbo.AAASTA_CONTACT CON2
JOIN dbo.AAASTA_ADDR_PER ADDR
ON (CON2.CON_PERSON_UID = ADDR.T_ADDR_PER_PER_ID))
```

Comment: It sounds like your inner SELECT statement (that defines the value you want to set ALIAS_KEY to) returns multiple values. Which of these values should ALIAS_KEY be set to?

Comment: I'm only asking for one substring.  If I run that as a select rather than a SET it returns one column of information.

Comment: The problem is that the query analyzer has deduced that the query has the `potential` of returning more than one result.

Comment: Haha well then it should know my intentions not the possibility of my actions!  Thanks for the logic help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.  It will update each row with the correct value:

```
UPDATE 
    dbo.AAASTA_CONTACT
SET 
    dbo.AAASTA_CONTACT.ALIAS_KEY = SUBSTRING(COALESCE(CAST(ADDR.ADDR_ZIPCODE AS NCHAR(5)), '     ') + COALESCE(CAST(UPPER(CON2.CON_LAST_NAME)AS NCHAR(5)), '     ')  + COALESCE(CAST(UPPER(CON2.CON_FST_NAME)AS NCHAR(5)), '     ') + COALESCE(CAST(UPPER(ADDR.ADDR_ADDR_NAME) AS NCHAR(5)), '     '),1,20)
FROM 
    dbo.AAASTA_CONTACT CON2
JOIN 
    dbo.AAASTA_ADDR_PER ADDR
    ON (CON2.CON_PERSON_UID = ADDR.T_ADDR_PER_PER_ID)
```

Comment: Ahh yeah that's it.  Guess my thinking was just off on how to go about doing it correctly.  Thanks for the help!